# Build.SERIAL is deprecated as of API 26: Android 8.0 Oreo

Tags: android, deprecated, android-8.0-oreo

I  just updated my application to API 26 and I'm trying to retrieve the serial of the device and I'm seeing that `Build.SERIAL` is deprecated on API 26.

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Build.getSerial()` as per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#getSerial()). Note that this requires the `READ_PHONE_STATE`  permission.

Answer (score 5):

**Build.SERIAL**

> *This field was deprecated in API level 26. **Use getSerial() instead.***

Note

> [...] For apps targeting SDK higher than Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1 this
>   field is set to UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build), it is deprecated since Android 8.0+ (API 26+) by the getter `getSerial()`.
Plus you need Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission.